# SQL QUERY - how to get child records with different types but from the same parent group

Tags: mysql, sql

I needed a query where to return the finished type records from the service_flow_actions table, but the records must belong to the service_flow table group where there are records that were given play

1. Table work_order

| id | company_id | closed | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | true | true |
| 2 | 1 | true | true |

2. Table service_flow

| id | work_order_id | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

3. Table service_flow_actions

| id | work_order_id | service_flow_id | type | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | finished | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | play | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | finished | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | play | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | pause | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | finished | 1 |

I had thought of something like that, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(service_flow_actions.*)
FROM service_flow_actions
INNER JOIN work_order ON service_flow_actions.work_order_id = work_order.id
LEFT JOIN service_flow_actions t ON work_order.id = t.work_order_id AND t.type = 'play' AND work_order.company_id = 37
WHERE work_order.company_id = 37 AND service_flow_actions.type = 'finished' AND work_order.closed = true AND work_order.status = true
```

Comment: Simplify your question, i.e. remove the work_order table, and write the expected output you will get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exists` clause helps in such situation, of course you can achieve the same result using the `join` clause, but I would go for simple solution first, unless I face performance issues.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM service_flow_actions
WHERE type = 'finished'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM service_flow_actions sub
    WHERE sub.service_flow_id = service_flow_actions.service_flow_id
    AND sub.type = 'play' 
)
```

Comment: thank you, your tip helped me a lot